# Moving dynamic CSS custom property out of line

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to implement CSP to force no in-line styling. I have one last item which is a pure CSS star rating. With in-line style I can use a custom property populated by php call to the database in order to render the stars (see below). But I can't figure out how to take that out of line to conform to security best practices.

CSS

```
:root {
     --star-size: 60px;
     --star-color: #fff;
     --star-background: #fc0;
}

 .Stars {
     --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-family: Times;
     line-height: 1;
}
 .Stars::before {
     content: '★★★★★';
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--star-background) var(--percent), var(--star-color) var(--percent));
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

HTML

```
<td><div class="Stars" style="--rating: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['RATING']); ?>;"></div></td>
```

Comment: How accurate of a gradient fill do you really need? Just make individual rules for each gradient step. For instance, if you have 5 stars and you don’t support fractions, you probably only need 6 rules (accounting for zero, too). If you support halves, 11 rules. If you support quarters, 21). Beyond that, can anyone really tell the difference? Then in PHP, just round.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing:

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to use the math functionality of css but statically defining each star worked.

````
[starrating="1"]{
     --percent: 20%;
}
[starrating="2"]{
     --percent: 40%;
}
[starrating="3"]{
     --percent: 60%;
}
[starrating="4"]{
     --percent: 80%;
}
[starrating="5"]{
     --percent: 100%;
}

 .Stars {
/*   --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);*/
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-family: Times;
     line-height: 1;
     --star-size: 60px;
     --star-color: #fff;
     --star-background: #fc0;
}
 .Stars::before {
     content: '★★★★★';
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--star-background) var(--percent), var(--star-color) var(--percent));
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}```
````